# Regex: How to search for a pattern but not include it in the output

Tags: regex

Is there a way to include a pattern in the search but then *not* include it in the final output?

I'm trying to find a way to take out just the state in the source code of an address. So my input is

```
<strong class="street-address">
 <address itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">10937 W Pico Blvd</span><br>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Los Angeles</span>, 
<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span> 
<span itemprop="postalCode">90064</span>
        </address>

        </strong>
```

(the actual source code is much longer for the page) but I want to look up using Regex:

```
postalCode">[0-9]{5}
```

and then only take out the snippet of `[0-9]{5}` instead of the `postalCode">` part in the beginning. The issue comes up when I have to search the whole source code as there is inevitably going to be other 5 digit numbers in the entire source code somewhere. Anyway to say, "look for postalCode">" and then take the next 5 digits if they fit the pattern [0-9] for 5 digits?

Comment: Which language are you using ? You could store the complete postcode lint in a variable $temp, then search $temp for a five digit integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look behind:

```
(?<="postalCode">)\d{5}
```

Look behinds, which have the syntax `(?<=...)`, *assert*, but do not *capture*, the input that immediately *precedes* the matched input. The match returned would be just the 5 digits.

Comment: How do I make it so the look behind can take in blank spaces? 
(?<="telephone">\s{1,}) gives me an "invalid pattern in look-behind"

Comment: Look behinds must be of known length. Since there are only two possible versions, a work around is to use an alternation (assuming "X" is the regex for your telephone number): `(?<="telephone">)X|(?<="telephone"> )X`, or you could capture the optional space as part of the telephone regex and trim it in your code.